# R to Python. How to mass dump multiple csv files into sqlite database using Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there a way to dump multiple csv files into a sqlite database using Python?

I'm trying to recreate some R code of mine with Python using sqlite3 and pandas.  The csv files would be rather large with 135 cols and 300 rows, so I'm trying to avoid having to name out the columns when I create the table in the sqlite database.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```py
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('dbex.db')
c = conn.cursor()

mydata_1 = pd.read_csv(file_name_ex)

c.execute("CREATE TABLE s1_results")
c.execute("INSERT INTO s1_results (mydata_1)")

#etc etc with more csv files and more tables
```

In R I could accomplish something similar via...

```r
createtableandimportdata = dbWriteTable(con, 's1_results', mydata_1)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just create SQL statements from CSV headers?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is exactly [**csv-to-sqlite**](https://pypi.org/project/csv-to-sqlite/) available on PyPi. You could either download the module as I mentioned below, or go to the [**PyPi**](https://pypi.org/project/csv-to-sqlite/) page and follow to the GitHub page. There you can see the [**source code**](https://github.com/zblesk/csv-to-sqlite/blob/master/csv_to_sqlite.py)

From PyPi:

Installs via

```
  pip install csv-to-sqlite
```

To find out more, run

```
  csv-to-sqlite –help
```

***Disclaimer***: this is not a package that I have created.